# Yii2 not showing error message on dropdownList

Tags: php, validation, drop-down-menu, yii2

I created a **dropdownList** for my project and I made the field as required in my model rules.

**In view**

```
use app\models\Constituency;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use kartik\widgets\Select



<?php
  $constituency=Constituency::find()->all();
  $listData=ArrayHelper::map($constituency,'constituency','constituency');

?>
<?php
   echo '<label class="control-label">Constituency</label>';
   echo Select2::widget([
   'model' => $model,
   'attribute' => 'place',
   'data' => $listData,
   'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a constituency'],
   'pluginOptions' => [
   'allowClear' => true
   ],
  ]);
?>
```

**In Models**

```
['place', 'required','message'=>'Place is required'],
```

Even I tired to give a custom error message for the field,But everything I tried was failed.
I am attaching the screenshot of the page here.
As you can see its shows no required error.

[image: Error Failed Image]

Can anyone tell me what I am missing??

Comment: And how are you rendering the "Mobile No" field?

Comment: <?= $form->field($model, 'phone')->textInput(['min' => 10,'type'=>'number']) ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use active field widget:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'place')->widget(Select2::className(), [
    'data' => $listData,
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a constituency'],
    'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
]) ?>
```

Comment: Thank you,Can you please say why its not worked in my method

Comment: You are missing additional containers for error messages that are being done automatically by active field widget - these containers are required for client side validation to properly display errors.